# Time formatting ruby

Tags: ruby

The following code scans a string for a date like this -- 06/10/2014 00:00

```
window1= line[13].scan(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d\:\d\d/) if line[13]
```

How do I save this as an object of the time class?

Comment: Does `line[13]` only contain the date string or are you extracting the date from a larger string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your format is day/month/year

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime('06/10/2014 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

Comment: you reversed your Hour and Minute symbols.

Answer (score 2):

```
window1 = DateTime.strptime(line[13], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') if line[13]
```

would be a good start.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html is a good reference.  In fact, ruby-doc.org in general is probably a good place to spend some time.

Answer (score 0):

`scan` can cause you to shoot yourself in the foot if you're not paying attention. Consider this:

```
str = 'foo 06/10/2014 00:00 bar'

str.scan(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d\:\d\d/) # => ["06/10/2014 00:00"]
```

`scan` returns an array of *all* matching patterns in the string. If the string was a bit different, you might get something unexpected:

```
str = 'foo 06/10/2014 00:00 bar 99/99/9999 99:99 baz'
str.scan(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d\:\d\d/) # => ["06/10/2014 00:00", "99/99/9999 99:99"]
```

Instead, if you know there's only one value just use a regular match to get a single value.

```
str[/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\s\d\d\:\d\d/] # => "06/10/2014 00:00"
```

Notice how you have a long series of repeated `\d` (digit character-sets) and escaped `/` delimiters ("`\/`"). Those can be reduced using some tricks to make the pattern more readable:

```
%r#\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+# # => /\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+:\d+/
str[%r#\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+#] # => "06/10/2014 00:00"
```

`\d+` means one-or-more digits, which reduces the repeated `\d`, but doesn't help get rid of the escaped delimiters. An alternate delimiter will help though, which is what `%r` lets us do. The first character following `%r` defines the delimiter so the pattern can go from

```
\/\d
```

to

```
/\d
```

It's a minor thing but it helps readability.

Using `\d+` can open up a new problem though, where more than two, or four, digits could be captured:

```
str = 'foo 1/22/55555 22:666666 bar'
str[%r#\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+#] # => "1/22/55555 22:666666"
```

Regex patterns were extended to allow us to specify how many characters are allowed:

```
str = 'foo 06/10/2014 00:00 bar'
str[%r#\d+/\d+/\d+ \d+:\d+#] # => "06/10/2014 00:00"
str[%r#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}#] # => "06/10/2014 00:00"

str = 'foo 1/22/55555 22:666666 bar'
str[%r#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}#] # => nil
```

Moving on to getting a Time value....

The Time class can parse the string captured and return a Time instance:

```
str = 'foo 06/10/2014 00:00 bar'
time_str = str[%r#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}#] # => "06/10/2014 00:00"

require 'time'
Time.parse(time_str).class # => Time
Time.parse(time_str) # => 2014-10-06 00:00:00 -0700
```

You have to be *very* careful with this though, because the format "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" is easily confused with "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm". The first is standard in the U.S., and the second is standard around the majority of the world, and languages don't like when there are collisions:

```
str = 'foo 01/31/2014 00:00 bar'
time_str = str[%r#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}#] # => "01/31/2014 00:00"

require 'time'
Time.parse(time_str).class # => 
Time.parse(time_str) # => 
# ~> 'local': argument out of range (ArgumentError)
```

Versus:

```
str = 'foo 31/01/2014 00:00 bar'
time_str = str[%r#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}#] # => "31/01/2014 00:00"

require 'time'
Time.parse(time_str).class # => Time
Time.parse(time_str) # => 2014-01-31 00:00:00 -0700
```

So, to fix that you MUST know what region/LOCALE your string is coming from otherwise you'll get random exceptions and/or messed up Month/Day values.

`parse` is convenient, but it's a two-edged sword, due to this problem. You can *try* to use `strptime` with a specific format string:

```
str = 'foo 01/31/2014 00:00 bar'
time_str = str[%r#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}#] # => "01/31/2014 00:00"

require 'time'
Time.strptime(time_str, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') # => 2014-01-31 00:00:00 -0700

str = 'foo 31/01/2014 00:00 bar'
time_str = str[%r#\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}#] # => "31/01/2014 00:00"
Time.strptime(time_str, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') # => 2014-01-31 00:00:00 -0700
Time.strptime(time_str, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') # => 
# ~>  'strptime': invalid strptime format - `%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' (ArgumentError)
```

But again, unless you KNOW what the format is, you can still run into problems. This is one of the really hard things about programming, and is why so often a site asks where someone is located. Guessing just doesn't work well.